# iPhone 'UISplitViewController is only supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape

I have a UITableView, with rows, when you click on each row you will see the detail view,I want this for iPhone,
if I rotate the device and select my row from the list, I have to  view the description.(I mean in the left I have to have my rows and in right my detail view) Rotating the device back to vertical and hide the detail view.

I used splitViewController, but I have an error,would you please check my code and let me know what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary 
*)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"ViewController" 
bundle:nil];
_nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:view];
//
MattersDetailView *detailVC = [[MattersDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MattersDetailView"
bundle:nil];
_nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"ecd555"] ];

splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[view,detailVC];
self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;



self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

and then adding this method to both viewController .m file

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return YES;
}
```

But I have this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:   
'UISplitViewController is only supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for `UISplitViewController`. It can only be used for an iPad app, not an iPhone app.

You need to remove the split view controller and replace it with something else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, do you know how can I do that in iPhone?

Comment: How to do what? Be specific.

Comment: having both table list and detail view in iPhone when I rotate the iPhone in landscape mode

Comment: You will have to create your own container view controller that can show both.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a **UITableView, with rows**, when you **click** on each **row** you will **see** the **detail view**,I want this for iPhone.

The behaviour you are after is typically handled differently on iPhone because the screens are smaller. As mentioned it's not really compatible with iPhones.

Either the transition to the detail view reflects either a simple attempt at Navigation or a humble detail view.

If it's Navigation you're after. Drawer Nav Menus are popular. Here is one that works with Storyboard and iOS7 and includes a tutorial. 
[AppCoda SlideNavMenu](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)

If it's just a transition based on using a cell touch as input the best thing I think for you is to create a new project (assuming you're using Xcode5)  using the Master Detail Template which replicates this functionality nicely.

Hope this helps.